# .Net Core - How to detect if a application is running?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I used to detect if a application as running with this method in .net:

```
    public static bool IsApplicationAlreadyRunning()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        return processes.Length > 1;
    }
```

But with .Net Core there is no Process class.
So how can you do the same thing?  Also is there some sort of similar class as Process in .Net Core?

Comment: no the process class exist and you have to include system.diagnostics

Comment: Looks like it should be available (if it isn't by default): https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Process/

Comment: Check out my similar solution to this problem, you might be able to adapt it for your use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358474/how-to-check-which-process-currently-has-focus

Comment: System.Threading.Mutex?